# Diagonal white lines in base maps in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, basemap

What is the reason that Openlayers 3 (3.20.1 to be exact) renders diagonal white lines on base maps such as Bing, Google etc under Chrome? Things are OK under Firefox and Edge. (Chrome version is: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit))

Please check the below image:

[image]

Comment: Same problem here, but it seems to work fine with the 4.1.0 version.

Comment: This problem still occurs in version 4.1.1